# Issue while running the js file on nightwatch

Tags: nightwatch.js, automation-testing

I am running Nightwatch through Vs code. Where inside the src folder test I have 2 js files one is a customer.js and the second is supplier.js. Now I want to run only customer.js using command **npx nightwatch -e chrome**

How can I run single js file

I am running Nightwatch through Vs code. Where inside the src folder test I have 2 js files one is a customer.js and the second is supplier.js. Now I want to run only customer.js using command **npx nightwatch -e chrome**

How can I run single js file

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
npx nightwatch [filepath]
```

Replace `[filepath]` with the filepath of your JS file from the current folder. Something like:

```
node_modules/nightwatch/examples.tests/jsfilename.js
```

So that:

```
npx nightwatch node_modules/nightwatch/examples.tests/customer.js
```